# Is it possible for a ListView to have a child view

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native

My Native iOS has TabBarController as root view controller. I have a PageViewController on the home screen(which is a container view) where 1 of the views supports React-Native

**Goal**: **Display Pop Up View while allowing user to switch tabs**

I have tried using a modal & the Alert API for displaying. The pop up works perfectly but both  mask over the entire screen & the only way to resume interaction is dismissing by pressing the **CANCEL** button in Alert. The Masking makes switching tabs not possible.

Since I can't remove the mask for modal or alertView, I am instead trying to render a view which is a child of ListView.
Here's my render() function

```
     return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>  
            <ListView 
               onEndReachedThreshold={-5}
               renderFooter={this._renderFooter}
               onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
               contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
               dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
               renderRow = {(rowData) => Row(rowData)}>

              <View style={styles.popUpStyle}>

              </View>

         </ListView>
       </View>
    )
 }
```

My StyleSheets is as follows

```
list: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems : 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    opacity : 1
},
popUpStyle : {

     width: widthOfScreen - 50,
     height: heightOfScreen/3,
     backgroundColor:'#000000',
     borderRadius: 5,
     shadowColor:'#000000',
     shadowRadius:5,
     shadowOpacity:0.8
}
```

I was expecting a view to appear at the center of the screen as ListView's based on the styles I added but alas there is nothing. Can a listView have a child View? More importantly can I make a pop up view without a mask?

Comment: Why is this tagged Android?

Comment: @ChantellOsejo tagged cause the Force is strong with React-Native & some Android engineers might have turned to the dark side.

Comment: So basically you want a view to popup in the middle of the screen while allowing users to still use the tab navigation without having to close the view? If not, sorry but can you explain it more?

Comment: @MattAft a pop up view at the center of the screen without a mask basically.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a listView have a child View?

Not that I know of.

> More importantly can I make a pop up view without a mask?

Of course you can. You just need some `absolute` magic. I do something similar to show "toasts":

The styles:

```
component: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    alignItems: 'center'
},
content: {
    backgroundColor: red,
    borderRadius: 0,
    padding: 10,
    height: 56,
    justifyContent: 'center'
},
text: {
    color: white,
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 18
}
```

The component:

```
<View style={styles.component} pointerEvents='none'>
    <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.text}>{this.state.text}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

My "toasts" aren't interactive but that's an exercise left for you.

Comment: Here's the issue I have `s`

Comment: Chuck my previous comment.. Here's the issue I have ,  the container View has List View & the toast view. The toast view needs to appear over ListView.  This  does not solve my problem. @Eldelshell

Comment: A toast is shown on top of all other components, but it has to be placed on the correct place, not inside the ListView